# Ionic3, Angular 2, rxjs object assign page variable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ionic3

I am doing Ionic3 project. and here's a question.
back-end : I used Rxjs with Firebase which is really simple and nice for realtime data.
Front code is here:

I want my data to keep consistency. so I made a service that brings data and assign to each page variable like this.

[.ts file]

```
public dogModel = new dogModel();
constructor(
,public testService: TestService) {
this.dogModel = this.testService.dogModel;
}
```

[html file]

```
<div>{{dogModel.state}}</div>
```

and it works really well. when data is changed in service, I don't know how the service data re-assign to page variable at all.
and one more,
if I change my code like this,

```
this.dogModel.state = this.testService.dogModel.state;
```

I can see the log changing data in service, but couldn't see any change in page.
does anybody know this?

part of my service.ts

```
constructor(
      public db: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {
    db.object( this.firebaseURL + '/dogState/test1234')
      .subscribe( (dogState) => {
        Object.assign(this.dogModel, <dogModel>dogState);

        console.log(this.dogModel);
      });
```

Comment: It is likely that the data has not returned whenever the constructor of your component runs. You could use a subject to subscribe to changes of the data in the service.

Comment: @0mpurdy - Yeah I did.


[Service.ts]
db.object( this.firebaseURL + '/mmumesState/test1234')
      .subscribe( (mmumesState) => { assign Data to object });

But I want my code clean, so I did subscribe one time only in Service. 

Should I call subscribe function in every pages that I am going to use data?

Comment: That is not shown here in the code you have posted? Could you include it?

Comment: thx for comments. I edited.

and I declare variable in service.ts and save my data local <dogModel> variable

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine changes are fed back to the UI because of events firing that are listened to. I'm assuming you are talking about updating data in the Firebase console, and your app immediately shows changes on screen of Ionic app. The beauty of subscribe! Probably using ReactiveFormsModule right?